# How to allow failures when saving multiple entities at once?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

So, I have potentially hundreds of rows that need to be inserted into a database. There is no validation validating uniqueness of the data.

However, in the database, there is a constraint among 3 columns that when combined, must be unique. Sometimes, this uniqueness fails, and the entire save operation fails.

Is there a way to ignore that failure in the `Table::saveMany()` call and continue to save all other records? Maybe log the error for later, but still continue on saving the rest of the records, instead of just outright failing the whole operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, look at the API description and the source code for `Table::saveMany()`, it's simply saving all entities in a loop that will stop and rollback the transaction in case `Table::save()` fails.

> The records will be saved in a transaction which will be rolled back if any one of the records fails to save due to failed validation or database error.

**https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_saveMany**

If you want to allow failures, then you have to handle that on your own, save each record, catch possible exceptions, and check the save operation result. Here's a quick & dirty example, where `$table` is the table via which to save, and `$entities` is an array of entities:

```
$result = $table->getConnection()->transactional(
    function () use ($entities, $table) {
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            try {
                $result = $table->save($entity, ['atomic' => false]);
            } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
                $result = $exception;
            }

            if ($result !== true) {
                // log an error...
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Using Transactions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting Multiple Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records)**

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth Compared to what?

Comment: Compared to just doing a loop and calling save on each entity.

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth Then the answer is no, as that is exactly what `Table::saveMany()` is doing internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a couple approaches to this issue.

1. Instead of using `Table::saveMany()` do a loop and just use `Table::save()` and keep a record of what has failed so you can investigate it later.
2. Split your big job into smaller batches. If you have to say say 1,000 records, split that into 100 records batches and use `Table:saveMany()` for each batch. This way when something fails only the current batch with fail and not the entire save process.
3. Kind of dangerous (and **NOT** recommended) is to override the `Table::save()` method to not fail even if it could not store the records.